# Use of an unassigned local string variable

Tags: c#, variables, return-value

Im trying to set a function to read values from an xml file

The function is as following..

```
public string XmlReadValue(string FilePath, string Element, string SubElement)
    {
        XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
        xml.Load(FilePath);

        XmlNodeList Elements = xml.SelectNodes("//" + Element);
        string Valuee;

        foreach (XmlNode Elemente in Elements)
        {
            Valuee = Elemente.SelectSingleNode(SubElement).InnerText;
        }
        return Valuee;
    }
```

When i return the value to `Valuee` it says `Use of an unassigned local variable 'Valuee'`

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: it is possible that selectnodes return nothing and your foreach loop never executed.So value is never assigned...

Comment: Have you looked at the right side under the section "Related"?

Comment: @Selman22 Ahaaaaaaaaaaa o.O

Comment: @TimSchmelter yes i did but it's all different situations and i still couldn't figure out what's wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `Elements` is empty you will never affect a value to `Valuee`.

You should initialize it like this :

```
string Valuee = "";
```

Answer (score 4):

This is because `Valuee` may never actually be set (if `Elements` has no values).

You can get around this by doing: `string Valuee = string.Empty;`

Answer (score 2):

`string Valuee;` doesn't assign to anything.

Set to null or empty string instead:

```
string Valuee = String.Empty; // change made here

foreach (XmlNode Elemente in Elements)
{
    Valuee = Elemente.SelectSingleNode(SubElement).InnerText;
}
return Valuee;
```